# Uploaded Laravel project on 000WebHost that's not working

Tags: php, laravel, web-hosting, laravel-5.6

I recently uploaded my laravel blog project on **000WebHost**, after that I redirected to URL http://laravelcreativeblog.000webhostapp.com/, but I saw this error `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`, this error is displayed two times one after the other. So I googled that and finally I reached to the a solution that there is an error in `APP_KEY` which I found here `/public_html/storage/logs/laravel.log` and error at last is:

> `[2018-10-18 15:44:47] production.ERROR: No application encryption key
>   has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0):
>   No application encryption key has been specified. at
>   /storage/ssd1/217/7530217/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php:42)
>   [stacktrace]`

So I generated Application Key from CMD by `php artisan key:generate` and put in the .ENV File but again getting that error.
This is all I done, so any suggestions???

Comment: use php artisan key:generate command to generate key

Comment: i guess this may be an issue of putting code in wrong directory OR mis matched configuration. So try to put debug code in the index.php file and die; this was you will get better idea.

Comment: Please see the last two line of my question.

Comment: @Exception in local server its working very well, there is no error in there.

Comment: @Shanukk bro I'm on the web server not on local server

Comment: If you check the error log again after setting the application key, what's the new error?

Comment: @fubar the error is same. I think that I generated the App Key locally and then put into server so this is the error I think and 000webhost free service can't support SSH Shell, so any suggestion how to generate App_key into server

Comment: @UsmanDeveloper you should manually specified the APP_KEY from .env into config/app.php and please try

Comment: Make sure you move the application outside of your `public_html/` folder, because right now your entire application (including log files with database passwords) is public on the internet. If your host requires you to use the `public_html/` folder, then create a symlink from `public_html/` to `public/`

Comment: The key doesn't HAVE to be generated via the php artisan command it's just a nifty way of doing it just generate own key and manually add it to the .env file.

Comment: @Shanukk I have added APP_KEY into `config/app.php` not worked.

Comment: @TravisBritz thanks, but it's now throwing this error `Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.` how to solve it i have moved out of publoic_html

Comment: @UsmanDeveloper that's hard to answer without knowing what exactly you changed. Did you also create a symlink from `public/` to your web host's website root folder (`public_html/`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the error the error was that **000WebHost** does not support **.ENV** file variables, so we must add all .env detials into `config/app.php` file and database details into `config/database.php`. Read the last FAQ here, https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/deploy-laravel-project-into-000webhost-site/127323 for more details(only for **000WebHost**).

Answer (score 3):

When you receive "No application encryption key" error:

1. be sure that you have `.env` file in root directory
2. run `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: Thanks bro it worked and not throwing that error but now its throwing this error `Connection refused` and how I use php artisan migrate?

Comment: what kind of connection? is your db up and running?

Comment: check that DB_CONNECTION, DB_HOST, DB_DATABASE, DB_PORT, DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD is set correctly in .env file, I think this will fix your error ;)

Comment: `APP_NAME="Laravel Creative Blog"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:QQvJhT6HMVkOcTvDiP0jySIlHsMtq2JSGdcl5kREF1Q=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://laravelcreativeblog.000webhostapp.com/

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=id7530217_laravelcreativeblog
DB_USERNAME=myUser`

Comment: @UsmanDeveloper, you’re going to want to change your app key again now that you’ve just published it online.